# How to remove extra content of XML/GPX files and make them valid again in Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, gpx

```
 ...
    </trk>
</gpx>
        <trkpt lat="53.502100503614564" lon="10.065932731189879">
            <ele>0.0</ele>
            <time>2017-10-15T11:42:39.916+0000</time>
            <speed>0.3</speed>
        </trkpt>
```

This is the end of a GPX file i would like to parse. Unfortunately with `gpxpy` and `lxml` i cannot parse the file and get an error message instead. All of the uesed parsers cannot handle the extra content after the final closing with `</gpx>`. It seems like they can only parse it entirely and not partially. Is that true?

I tried to solve it by using the `open(gpxfile,'r+').read().find("</gpx>")` function in order to locate the end of the file and overwrite anything else with `f.write('')` after using `f.seek(positionOfEnd)`.

Using truncate, to truncate the rest of the file is unfortunately not working in the `r+` writing mode.

Also i tried to use `etree.iterparse` to parse the file line by line, but it also didn't worked out for me.

**Here the code im using:**

```
# with gpxpy
_GPX = open(gpxfile,'r')
gpx = gpxpy.parse(_GPX)

# with lxml
for elem in etree.iterparse(path+"\\"+file, events=('start','end'), tag="gpx"):
   print(elem)
```

using `gpxpy` i get:

```
raise mod_gpx.GPXXMLSyntaxException('Error parsing XML: %s' % str(e), e)
gpxpy.gpx.GPXXMLSyntaxException: Error parsing XML: Extra content at the end of the document, line 16, column 3 (line 16)
```

using `lxml` i get:

```
File "src\lxml\iterparse.pxi", line 208, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src\lxml\etree.c:155949)
File "file:/C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/test/Mission%202.gpx", line 16
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 16, column 3
```

What i tried instead was:

```
f = open(path+"\\"+file,'r+')
pos = f.read().find("</gpx>")
f.seek(pos+1)
f.write('testEdit')
f.close
```

but the String 'testEdit' was not placed as expected, but somewhere in the middle of the file, not even close to a gpx tag.

How can i handle this problems easily? What else can i try? I'm using Win7 and python2.7

Comment: What error message did you get when using `lxml`? Would you mind showing your codes?

Comment: what's wrong with opening the file, editing it in code then just feeding it directly as a string to an xml? its the simplest solution by far and you havent mentioned it

Comment: @kitman0804 i updated my post with code and error messages
@AntiMatterDynamite well, this is what i'm actually trying to do, but i'm not able to locate the exact position of the closing `</gpx>` tag and therefore it's not possible to overwrite the file at the correct position. What i want is to skip to the last valid position and the erase anything else below.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that my approach isn't a good practice to handle gpx/xml/html data, but you may try

```
import re
from lxml import etree

f = open(gpxfile, 'r')
gpx = re.search(r'\<gpx\>(.|\n)*\<\/gpx\>', f.read()).group(0) # Give you '<gpx>...</gpx>'
tree = etree.fromstring(gpx)
```

---

You may also try `BeautifulSoup` (maybe a better approach), which can handle the `<trkpt>` tag outside `<gpx>`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open(gpxfile, 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')
```